# Удалить из List элементы с одинаковыми значениями полей

Tags: java, list

Есть класс User, у которого есть свои ID, имя, количество отправленных сообщений и дата, когда эти сообщения были отправлены.

Объекты в коллекцию поступают из базы такого вида:

```
ID  Name Сообщения  Дата
1   test3   300 2018-11-02
2   test2   228 2018-11-02
3   test3   124 2018-11-05
4   test4   24  2018-11-03
5   test3   242 2018-11-01
6   test6   334 2018-11-03
7   test7   32  2018-11-03
8   test8   22  2018-11-03
9   test9   245 2018-11-03
10  test10  145 2018-11-03
```

Где каждая строка - один элемент в List<User>

Проблема в том, что записи в таблице дублируются, меняется у них только дата и кол-во сообщений, а имя остается то же. И, если я хочу получить статистику сообщения за определенный период, то я получу множество разных объектов с одним и тем же Name. К примеру, в List-е, созданном по таблице выше объектов с Name test3 аж 3 штуки, а мне хотелось бы чтобы была одна, но с кол-вом сообщений всех троих.

Вопрос: Как можно удалить из List все объекты, у которых одинаковый Name, кроме одного, и к его кол-ву сообщений прибавить кол-во удаленных?

Comment: возможно, имеет смысл написать отдельно получение пользователей с уникальными именами, тогда ничего не нужно будет фильтровать на стороне Java, или если нужно только их количество, то его и возвращать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю в каком виде у вас хранится дата и какова должна быть логика её редукции, поэтому не учитываю её в примере.

```
class User {
    private String name;
    private int messages;

    public User(String name, int messages) {
        this.name = name;
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public User(User another) {
        this.name = another.name;
        this.messages = another.messages;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public User merge(User another) {
        this.messages += another.messages;
        return this;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s: %d", name, messages);
    }
}

List<User> merged = users.stream()
                         .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.toMap(
                              User::getName,
                              User::new,
                              User::merge),
                            m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())));
```

Естественно, можно обойтись и без определения дополнительных методов в классе `User`, определив их в виде лямбд в коллекторе

```
Collectors.toMap(
  User::getName,
  u -> new User(u.getName(), u.getMessage()),
  (a, b) -> {
      a.setMessages(a.getMessages() + b.getMessages());
      return a;
  })
```

Но это, очевидно, менее чистый код.

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то как-то так:

```
public class Data {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String massage;
    private LocalDate localDate;

    public Data(int id, String name, String massage, LocalDate localDate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.massage = massage;
        this.localDate = localDate;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMassage() {
        return massage;
    }

    public void setMassage(String massage) {
        this.massage = massage;
    }

    public LocalDate getLocalDate() {
        return localDate;
    }

    public void setLocalDate(LocalDate localDate) {
        this.localDate = localDate;
    }

}

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>(asList(
                new Data(1, "name1", "message1", LocalDate.now()),
                new Data(2, "name2", "message2", LocalDate.now()),
                new Data(3, "name2", "message3", LocalDate.now()),
                new Data(4, "name3", "message4", LocalDate.now()),
                new Data(5, "name3", "message5", LocalDate.now()),
                new Data(6, "name3", "message6", LocalDate.now())
        ));
        Map<String, Long> dataMap = dataList.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Data::getName, counting()));
        dataMap.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("key: " + key + " -> value: " + value));

    }

}
```